# $routeProvider does not route after selection from a dropdown array of JSON objects

Tags: angularjs, routes

My first route (after doing some tutorials) has 2 problems. I am trying to insert partials into an ng-view tag in the index.html page. First, $routeProvider sort of works, but the only line that does anything is the .otherwise() expression. Secondly, the controller code to change the page from an ng-dropdown selection changes the URL, but does not change to the new display page. I have to manually click the reload arrow to change the display.

My app config code for routing is:

```
residenceApp.config(['$translateProvider', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ( $translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider.when("/index", { templateUrl: "partials/home.html" });
  $routeProvider.when("/partials/postApartment4Rent", { templateUrl: "partials/postApartment4Rent.html" });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({ templateUrl: "partials/home.html" });
```

I can get to any partials page I want via the .otherwise() expression, but the others have no effect. The URL shows for partials/postApartment4Rent.html, but the display does not change. I have to manually click on the reload arrow to get the new page.

The partials pages have anchor expressions like the following. With no .html, I get 404 file not found. These act like plain anchors, with no routing going on.

```
<a href = "postApartment4Rent.html">Rent-link</a>
<a href = "index.html">Home</a>
```

I'm using angular-dropdowns which shows a dropdown menu when its button is clicked. The user selects from the dropdown and that creates a JSON object containing the path addition to the base URL. The controller is below.

```
residenceApp.controller('PostButtonController', ['$translate', '$scope', 'changePostDdFactory', '$location', 
  function ( $translate, $scope, ddSelections, $location ){
  //get the dropdown array from a factory & display it - it works
  $scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function( newVal ) {
    if (newVal && newVal.text) {
      $scope.newPage = "'/" + newVal.val + "'";
      alert('newPage is: ' + $scope.newPage ); //newPage is: '/postApartment4Rent'
      $location.path($scope.newPage); //URL changes, but no new page unless Reload
    }
  }, true);
}]);
```

I have the following HTML5 base in the HTML head.

```
<base href="http://localhost/angular-oPost/app/">
```

My HTML for index.html also contains the following anchor just above the div for the dropdown button. Its only purpose is to be a landing spot for $routeProvider. It does not/should not display as a link.

```
<a href="/index"></a>
```

The rest of index.html is a bunch of divs that contain either paras, inputs, or the ng-dropdowns button. I'd be glad to post some if it helps, but it seems pretty normal.

Comment: The "TypeError: undefined is not a function" problem was caused by having $location in the $watch function. $location is inherited from the parent function and duplication causes an error. The error message is poorly worded to the point of being misleading, IMO. Problem #2 is fixed. Problem #1 is some complicated interaction of the <base> statement, the routes and the <a> statement formats. I now get the proper URL at times, but the partial does not load, and with other <a>'s I get duplicated path statements. Its some format mess.

Comment: The #1 problem with $routeProvider has bizarre behavior. When I click on a dropdown selection, the URL changes per the controller above, but the display never changes. Then when I click the reload/refresh circular arrow, I get the proper page display. At the new page, when I click on the home page anchor link, it does not route back to app/index.html  I goes to various other existing or non-existing pages, but not to the <base>.

Comment: It seems that a click on the link causes an attempt to go to that exact link - that is $routeProvider and templateURL are not involved in the action. Said another way, it seems no routing is actioned. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem of only routing off the .otherwise() expression was solved by changing the first .when() expression to

```
.when("/", { templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller: "LanguageChoiceController" } )
```

The second problem of showing the new URL but not loading the page when a user selects from a dropdown was solved with changes in several places. The user click on a JSON object in a dropdown array is outside the $digest cycle. Tutorials and books don't talk about this case, so it took a lot of experimenting. New code in the dropdown controller became, as follows to get the click recognized and actioned:

```
$scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function( newVal ) {
  if (newVal && newVal.text) {
    $scope.newPage = $timeout( function(){
    //fire a click - via code from http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2011/11/29/programatically-fire-crossbrowser-click-event-with-javascript/
      function fireClick(node){
      if ( document.createEvent ) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
        node.dispatchEvent(evt);    
        } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
        node.fireEvent('onclick') ; 
        } else if (typeof node.onclick == 'function' ) {
            node.onclick(); 
        }
      }
      var theNode = document.getElementById( newVal.val );
    }
    fireClick(theNode);
  }, 10 )
}, true); //end of $watch
```

I tried another 'simpler' approach with the code below, but it had no impact

```
$scope.newPage=function()$timeout(function(){{angular.element(document.getElementById( newVal.val )).triggerHandler('click');}, 10);};
```

The router code (using 1.3.2 for both angularjs and angular-route) is straightforward, as follows:

```
        .when("/partials/postApartment4Rent", { templateUrl: "partials/postApartment4Rent.html", 
        controller: "LanguageChoiceController" } )
```

The anchor statement is below. It worked when placed either in index.html or in one of the partials html fragments.  I put it in the partials/home.html fragment

```
<a href="#/partials/postApartment4Rent" id="postApartment4Rent"></a>
```

This is odd because it requires "#/" even though I specified HTML5 in the router config statement. However, it would not route unless the "#/" was in the beginning of the href.

In sum, it routes, but does not get the Good Housekeeping award because some of the URLs are messy, and not HTML5. However, it gets the Arts & Crafts award because it routes, and the back and forward browser arrows work even though the browser shows odd/not HTML5 URLs.

Comment: $window.location.href loads a new page, but does not use ng-view in index.html. A better solution is needed, but I have not found it yet.

Comment: If anyone finds a way to use HTML5 style anchor statements and gets nice clean HTML5 URLs, please post your solution in a comment.